# How do I submit a form to an MVC controller action using a blazor EditForm component?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using blazor I would like to submit the form to an MVC controller action once validation has taken place. Can I make the form behave like a regular form? The following doesn't work because the `action` attribute is ignored.

```
<EditForm EditContext="@_modelContext" OnSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" action="/" method="post">
```

The form values tell the controller what file send to the response stream.

I don't see away to bypass the behaviour of `EditForm`. Is this possible?

Comment: How can server site control could be transform into client site element? The answer is by rendering on the server. Btw you can use regular element with different approach, eg. using server scripting for any injection or binding needs.